# Find time-lag between groups in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time, grouping, lag

Let's suppose I want to estimate the time lag between two groups within a `data.frame`.

Here an example of my data:

```
df_1 = data.frame(time = c(1,3,5,6,8,11,15,16,18,20), group = 'a') # create group 'a' data
df_2 = data.frame(time = c(2,7,10,13,19,25), group = 'b') # create group 'b' data

df = rbind(df_1, df_2) # merge groups

df = df[with(df, order(time)), ] # order by time
rownames(df) = NULL #remove row names

> df
   time group
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     3     a
4     5     a
5     6     a
6     7     b
7     8     a
8    10     b
9    11     a
10   13     b
11   15     a
12   16     a
13   18     a
14   19     b
15   20     a
16   25     b
```

Now I need to subtract the `time` observation from group `b` to the `time` observation from group `a`.
i.e. 2-1, 7-6, 10-8, 13-11, 19-18 and 25-20.

```
# Expected output
> out
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find indices of `b` and subtract the `time` value from it's previous index.

```
inds <- which(df$group == "b")
df$time[inds] - df$time[inds - 1]
#[1] 1 1 2 2 1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. First add a column by basic logic of the appearance of group `b` with `transmute` and a subtraction of the preceding column. Then `filter` to just the results, and convert to vector with `deframe`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  transmute(result = if_else(group == "b", time - lag(time), 0)) %>% 
  filter(result != 0) %>%
  deframe()
```

result:

```
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 5
```